# Maximum and minimum values in matrix R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 3D matrix of float values, and I need the maximum and minimum values inside, like:

```
[[1]]
0.1 0.3 0.6 0.8
0.09 0.1 0.4 0.6

[[2]]
0.08 0.2 0.5 0.75
0.01 0.3 0.5 0.55
```

generated by:

```
m <- list(matrix(c(0.1,0.3,0.6,0.8,
                    0.09,0.1,0.4,0.6),2,4,byrow=TRUE),
           matrix(c(0.08,0.2,0.5,0.75,
                    0.01,0.3,0.5,0.55),2,4,byrow=TRUE))
```

max is 0.8 and min 0.01

I try max() and min() functions but doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

## Toy data:

```
> m1<-matrix(runif(8,1,100),2,4)
> m1
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 98.88260 97.13486  2.712315 35.09616
[2,] 43.90468 99.59167 41.873303 94.19843
> m2<-matrix(runif(8,1,100),2,4)
> m2
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 26.61785 61.11184 42.28846 55.87778
[2,] 49.27263 59.28607 46.72659 76.24321
> l<-list(m1,m2)
```

## Calculate max and min

```
> lapply(l,FUN = max)
[[1]]
[1] 99.59167

[[2]]
[1] 76.24321

> lapply(l,FUN = min)
[[1]]
[1] 2.712315

[[2]]
[1] 26.61785
```

Also, you can have both in one line of code: `lapply(l,FUN = range)` (Thanks to Joseph Wood for this last suggestions. See comments)

Comment: You could also get both the `min` and `max` in one call with `range` (`lapply(l, range)`). Nice work.

Comment: Yes, you right, I will consider it to my answer